# Enabling profile via rest api is not giving phaseTimes while fetching Active Requests via Rest Api

Tags: couchbase

I have enabled profile in my CB server, profile is set to phases.

Executed this curl command :-

`curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8093/admin/settings' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --header 'Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpwYXNzd29yZA==' \ --data-raw '{ "profile": "phases" }'`

so the profile got updated from `off` to `phases` now as shown below :-

```
{
"auto-prepare": false,
"completed": {
    "aborted": null,
    "threshold": 1000
},
"completed-limit": 4000,
"completed-threshold": 1000,
"controls": false,
"cpuprofile": "",
"debug": false,
"functions-limit": 16384,
"keep-alive-length": 16384,
"loglevel": "INFO",
"max-index-api": 4,
"max-parallelism": 1,
"memprofile": "",
"mutexprofile": false,
"n1ql-feat-ctrl": 12,
"pipeline-batch": 16,
"pipeline-cap": 512,
"prepared-limit": 16384,
"pretty": false,
"profile": "phases",
"request-size-cap": 67108864,
"scan-cap": 512,
"servicers": 24,
"timeout": 0
}
```

But when querying for active requests ie `http://localhost:8093/admin/active_requests`
I am getting the below mentioned output :-

```
[
{
    "clientContextID": "1a1d8828-b06a-46f3-a5fe-13a9841cee18",
    "elapsedTime": "1.4613172s",
    "executionTime": "1.4610895s",
    "phaseCounts": {
        "fetch": 2304,
        "primaryScan": 2727
    },
    "phaseOperators": {
        "authorize": 1,
        "fetch": 1,
        "primaryScan": 1
    },
    "requestId": "6f44adea-9752-491d-936d-b36c7d450029",
    "requestTime": "2020-08-27T21:11:28.344Z",
    "scanConsistency": "unbounded",
    "state": "running",
    "statement": "SELECT * FROM `beer-sample`",
    "users": "Administrator"
}
]
```

Why the phaseTimes section is not coming in my case.

But if do the same via Couchbase query workbench i can see the phaseTimes section.
please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If profile is set (not off) PhaseTimes will be included in active_requests, completed_requests. From 6.50+ by default these are included even profile off.

```
curl -u user:pass http://localhost:8093/admin/active_requests

This list all active requests. But will not give PhaseTimes. only single active request gives PhaseTimes via admin endpoint 

Example: curl -u user:pass -XPOST http://localhost:8093/admin/active_requests/<request-uuid>

Alternative for all active_requests is use query endpoint with select query as follows.

curl -u user:pass -v http://localhost:8093/query/service -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{"statement":"SELECT a.* FROM system:active_requests AS a"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that really helped. But i have 1 query, if i call /query/service with the select statement for active_requests, then i get the select  * from active_requests statement as well in the collection of active requests. Though in this case all the active requests contains phaseTimes.. So is there any other way?

Comment: Use WHERE clause to filter out.  Also track https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-41206